# jQuery - clearing an HTML table before loading new data on ajax post success

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

```
<select id="group" name="group" onchange="generateList(this.value);">
     <?php foreach ($userGroup as $item) { ?>
        <option value="<?= $item->appsGroupId ?>"><?= $item->userGroupName ?></option>
     <?php } ?>
</select>
```

This is a dropdown list and on change event of which I am calling the following javascript function which initiates an ajax post to a PHP function

```
function generateList(id)
{
    var packages = "";
    var groupId = {"group_id" : id};

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: groupId,
        url: "<?= base_url() ?>apps_users/seeGroup",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            packages = jQuery.parseJSON(data.packages);
            var vm = function() {
                var self = this;
                self.records = ko.observableArray(packages);
                $.each(self.records(), function(i, record){
                    record.packageId = record.packageId;
                    record.packageName = record.packageName;
                })
            }
            ko.applyBindings(new vm());
        },
        error: function(error) {
          alert(error.status + "<--and--> " + error.statusText);
        }
    });
};
```

And on success of the ajax post(calls a PHP function which returns json response). With the response i'm populating a simple HTML table which is below:

```
<div class="container" id="assignPackage">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="packageTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Package Name</th>
            </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody data-bind="foreach: records">
          <tr>
            <td data-bind="text:packageId" > </td>
            <td data-bind="text:packageName"> </td>                
         </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>    
<br><br>
</div>
```

Now the problem is when I change the drop down the table is being populated with the new data but the old ones are remaining. On dropdown change what I want is to clear the old data in the HTML table and load new data after ajax post.

Comment: is that table written in your static HTML code, or it is created inside ko.applyBindings() function?

Comment: table is written in static html code and i'm binding data to the table after ajax post success. As you can see that i'm using data-bind to every td @WorldFS

Answer (score 0):

ok. Manipulating the DOM in this way is not the best way:

```
  success: function(data) {
                 $('#assignPackage').hide();
                console.log(packages); console.log(group);           
                ko.applyBindings({ 
                        records : JSON.parse(data.packages)
                    });
                  $('#assignPackage').show();
            },
```

if the table data is very long, I would suggest you, using a dynamic plugin (like jquery datatables).

Comment: Not working. With your solution the whole assignPackage div is being hidden on dropdown change.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `$('#packageTable tr').remove();` before the `ko.applyBindings` is called in the success function:

```
function generateList(id)
{
    var groupId = {"group_id" : id};

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: groupId,
        url: "<?= base_url() ?>apps_users/seeGroup",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(packages); console.log(group);

            $('#packageTable tr').remove();

            ko.applyBindings({ 
                    records : JSON.parse(data.packages)
                });
        },
        error: function(error) {
          alert(error.status + "<--and--> " + error.statusText);
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Not working. With your solution the tr of the table is removed on dropdown change.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, I think all you need to do is to clear all texts in  before setting the new value.

Call this before calling ko.applyBindings:

```
$("#packageTable").find("td").html('');
```

This will clear all texts (also all child elements) for all td under table#packageTable.

Comment: It doesn't clear anything ... the old data remains if I change dropdown

Comment: I tried in jsfiddle and it works... so I guess there might be some functions out there controlling that table too? Is that possible?

Comment: can you provide the jsfiddle link please ??

Comment: No it's not working....

Actually i'm calling a javascript function on the dropdown change and that function is initiating an ajax post and on success of the ajax post i'm binding data to the html table with the data from ajax post response. That's the whole scenario.

Comment: Well it's not possible for me to put a ajax call in jsfiddle... you can treat $(function(){}) in my jsfiddle as a ajax response and that code will clear the texts in td. Maybe you can post the code for applyBindings function, I think there might be a problem in that function.

Answer (score 0):

You Are using Knockout to bind Json.

Can you Post your Knockout Code?

or Use On body load

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      var records = {packageId:'',packageName'' }; 
       ko.applyBindings(records);
 });
```

and on ajax Success event just use

```
 records = JSON.parse(data.packages);
```

where records is global variable of javascript.

Comment: yes i'm using knockout js to bind json and I have posted my whole code above

Comment: This is happening because you are using ko.applyBindings multiple times i.e. whenever you chage your Dropdown Option.

Comment: I have edited my success function of the ajax post ..... now how can I solve the issue.

I mean where to put the ko.applyBindings to get my desired result.

Comment: Changed Code please Check. Use Document ready code i.e Body Load.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/code_psycho/6aqfr701/1/

here is my whole code. can you suggest me now please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72501/discussion-between-jishan-and-dot-net-learner).